# LinkedIn API - Get User Feed

Tags: php, linkedin-api

I am having trouble getting the feed of a users updates via the API.

I am authenticating just fine and am able to get the profile information but that is it..

Code:

```
$config['base_url'] = URL_FULL.'/networks.php?connect=3';   
$config['callback_url'] = URL_FULL.'/networks.php?connect=3&step=2'; 
$config['linkedin_access'] = LINKEDIN_KEY;
$config['linkedin_secret'] = LINKEDIN_SECRET;

$li = new LinkedIn(
  array(
    'api_key' => LINKEDIN_KEY, 
    'api_secret' => LINKEDIN_SECRET, 
    'callback_url' => $config['callback_url']
  )
);

$test = $li->setAccessToken($row['token']);
$info = $li->get('/people/~/network/updates');
print_r($info);
```

Error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'Request Error: Access to network denied. Raw Response: Array( [errorCode] => 0 [message] => Access to network denied [requestId] => GDXQ1QTFSQ [status] => 403 [timestamp] => 1399293102543)' in /var/www/social/includes/LinkedIn/linkedin.php:292Stack trace:#0 /var/www/social/includes/LinkedIn/linkedin.php(229): LinkedIn->_makeRequest('https://api.lin...', Array, 'GET', Array, Array)#1 /var/www/social/includes/LinkedIn/linkedin.php(197): LinkedIn->fetch('/people/~/netwo...', Array)#2 /var/www/social/includes/requests/getPosts.php(192): LinkedIn->get('/people/~/netwo...')#3 {main} thrown in /var/www/social/includes/LinkedIn/linkedin.php on line 292

**EDIT:**
This problem still racks my brain!

Comment: Can you confirm `LINKEDIN_KEY` and `LINKEDIN_SECRET` are placed correctly in configuration file?

Comment: Yes because when i do `$info = $li->get('/people/~:(first-name,last-name,positions)');` i get the profile for the logged in user

Answer (score 0):

The LinkedIn `api` has changed and the permissions also changed. You should check the link for more information on the changes, in the past I faced the same problem.

Permissions now are:

> Your Profile Overview, Your Full Profile, Your Email Address, Your Connections, Your Contact Info, Network Updates, Group Discussions, Invitations and Messages,

[Here more info on recent changes in the LinkedIn `api`](http://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/recent-changes-in-linkedin-api)